# Перенос с Windows 7 на Windows 10 программ, установленных не на диск С

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-7

Есть Windows 7. И программы установлены не на системный диск, а на другой, условно Z.

Хочу перейти на Windows 10. У которой сохранится тот же самый диск Z с теми программами. Но, скорее всего, работать не будут, ибо данные не занесены в систему, ибо, по сути, никогда не устанавливались.

Возможно ли как-то перенести эти сведения с одной системы на другую? Что для этого нужно (из реестра пути установки, копия папок из `AppData`, `Roaming`, прочие папки)?

Или проще всё убить и поставить заново?

P.S. Интересует именно не накат 10 на 7, а установка чистой десятки с нуля.

Comment: Сделайте обязательно резервную копию папки Users.

Answer (score 3):

Если будете переходить через обновление, то винда постарается максимально сохранить все данные/установленные программы, в т.ч. возможность их запуска и оставит возможность отката на предыдущую версию Windows. Вполне возможно, что не все программы после обновления смогут запуститься. В этом случае возможно поможет восстановление (некоторые установщики П/О имеют соотв. опцию в инсталяторах) Всё что не запустится можно попробовать переустановить. Возможно что они сохранят все настройки.

В случае чистовой установки (переустановки) сохранить данные не выйдет по той причине, которую вы описали в вопросе. Можно попытаться сохранить ключи реестра, файлы настроек и пр. но это танцы с бубном с непредсказуемыми последствиями. Проще переустановить всё заново.